# How to handle ajax success method return model in java script

Tags: javascript, spring

i am creating ajax call on Change on first drop down.Based on First drop down i am getting second drop down values.Though Ui i am sending selected customer name and trigger post method.Through back end i am return model object.How to handle this model in ajax success call.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
            var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'environments',
                data : {
                    selectedcustomername : value1
                },
                success : function(result) {
                    //how to handle model in this 
               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is controller layer code:

```
public ModelAndView getenvironments(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,@RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("selected cust name"+selectedcustomername);
        ModelAndView model = null;  
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<org.mvc.domain.Customer> customerList = loginDelegate.getCustomerList();
        List<org.mvc.domain.Environments> environmentnamesList = loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
        Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
        for(int i=0;i<environmentnamesList.size()-1;i++){
            customer.setEnvrironmentId(environmentnamesList.get(0));
            customer.setEnvironmentName(environmentnamesList.get(1));
        }
        map.put("customerList", customerList);
        map.put("environmentnamesList", environmentnamesList);
        model = new ModelAndView("welcome", "map", map);
        return model;

    }
```

This is my drop down ui code

```
<form:form method="get" commandName="frmSample" action="retrieve" modelAttribute="customer">
<b>Environment:</b>
                        <form:select path="EnvrironmentId" id="environmentName">                                                                                                                                                    
                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>
                        <form:options items="${map.environmentnamesList}" itemLabel="environmentName" itemValue="envrironmentId"/>                                                                                                                                                      
                        </form:select>
                     </td>
```

My First dropdown Ui:

```
<form:select path="CustomerId" id="customerDetails">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Customer</option>
     <form:options items="${map.customerList}"
     itemLabel="customerName" itemValue="customerId" />
    </form:select> <br>


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView executeLogin(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean,
            @ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
        response.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        ModelAndView model = null;
        try {
            boolean isValidUser = loginDelegate.isValidUser(
                    loginBean.getUsername(), loginBean.getPassword());
            if (isValidUser) {
                System.out.println("User Login Successful");
                request.setAttribute("loggedInUser", loginBean.getUsername());
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                List<org.mvc.domain.Customer> customerList = loginDelegate
                        .getCustomerList();
                map.put("customerList", customerList);
                model = new ModelAndView("welcome", "map", map);
            } else {

                model.addObject("loginBean", loginBean);
                request.setAttribute("message", "Invalid credentials!!");
                model = new ModelAndView("login");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: If call goes successfully in success then you can use `result.` put `debugger` and check which data are coming in result

Comment: i am getting result in firefox under html section..

Comment: If i tried to print result i am not getting any thing.

Answer (score 0):

For ModelAndView return type is used ModelAndViewResolverMethodReturnValueHandler, so it will not return you an json string.  I suggest you return a Map, and use the @ResponseBody like:

```
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getEnvironments(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,@RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("selected cust name"+selectedcustomername);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<org.mvc.domain.Customer> customerList = loginDelegate.getCustomerList();
        List<org.mvc.domain.Environments> environmentnamesList = loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
        Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
        for(int i=0;i<environmentnamesList.size()-1;i++){
            customer.setEnvrironmentId(environmentnamesList.get(0));
            customer.setEnvironmentName(environmentnamesList.get(1));
        }
        map.put("customerList", customerList);
        map.put("environmentnamesList", environmentnamesList);
        return map;

    }
```

Comment: Thank q.Now i am able to print the drop down values.but i more problem is there.after page refresh this dropdown is not retain the values.

Comment: On refresh page - if your first dropdown has an item selected you must call  method to load the scound, or better is fill secound from JSP if first has an selected option.

Comment: what is scound..i am not understand u r ans

Comment: on refresh my first drop down  has selected value.but this second dropdown is not having any value.because this rest call will triger only onchange of first dropdown..

Comment: the same javascript method used for on change first drop down. Extract a method and reuse it.

Comment: No it is not possible..because my first drop down values coming initial page load only..this is my url:  http://localhost:8001/dropdown/login...when i triger this one that time i am getting values.

Comment: mean i am saying at the time of triggering this url in my local my first dropdown values are loading..onchange of first dropdown i am displaying 2nd dropdown values..

Comment: OK, your first dropdown is fill from jsp an you have all values in html. on page ready  you can call to refresh your secound drop down. I am right ?

Comment: like:

$(document).ready( 
   loadScoundSelect();
   $("#customerDetails").change(function() { loadScoundSelect();});
 );

function loadSecoundSelect(){
    var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'environments',
                data : {
                    selectedcustomername : value1
                },
                success : function(result) {
               }
            });
}

Comment: if you want to help more, post your first dropdown load methods